# Grant User Privileges on MySQL Service in GitHub Actions

Tags: mysql, github-actions

In GitHub Actions, I have defined a MySQL service like this:

```
    env:
      MYSQL_ALLOW_EMPTY_PASSWORD: true
      MYSQL_DATABASE: localdb
        
    services:
      mysql:
        image: mysql/mysql-server:5.7
        ports:
          - 3306:3306
```

Now, when I connect to this service I get:

```
ERROR 1130 (HY000): Host '172.18.0.1' is not allowed to connect to this MySQL server
```

When I installed the same service locally using Docker, I solved the very same error with this code:

```
$ docker exec -it mysqldb bash# mysql -h localhost -u root -p

mysql> create user 'root'@'%' identified WITH mysql_native_password by '';
mysql> grant all privileges on *.* to 'root'@'%' with grant option;
```

Yet I have no idea how I would do the same inside the CI pipeline, since connecting to the server to execute queries already throws the above error.

How do I configure the MySQL server to accept connections?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The service probably just had the wrong image, this works:

```
    services:
      mysql:
        image: mysql:5.7
        env:
          MYSQL_ALLOW_EMPTY_PASSWORD: yes
          MYSQL_DATABASE: localdb
        ports:
          - 3306:3306
        options: --health-cmd="mysqladmin ping" --health-interval=10s --health-timeout=5s --health-retries=3
```

Comment: Doesn't the question mean how to add it using the same image? Changing to this image does not execute SQL files dump import for file in /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d correctly

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the `MYSQL_ROOT_HOST` environment variable to allow access from other services, as described [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/docker-mysql-more-topics.html#docker_var_mysql-root-host).

#### Before

```yaml
    services:
      mysql:
        env:
          MYSQL_ALLOW_EMPTY_PASSWORD: "yes"
          MYSQL_DATABASE: "localdb"

        image: "mysql/mysql-server:5.7"

        options: --health-cmd="mysqladmin ping" --health-interval=10s --health-timeout=5s --health-retries=3

        ports:
          - "3306:3306"
```

#### After

```yaml
    services:
      mysql:
        env:
          MYSQL_ALLOW_EMPTY_PASSWORD: "yes"
          MYSQL_DATABASE: "localdb"
          MYSQL_ROOT_HOST: "%"

        image: "mysql/mysql-server:5.7"

        options: --health-cmd="mysqladmin ping" --health-interval=10s --health-timeout=5s --health-retries=3

        ports:
          - "3306:3306"
```